# How to find a function that is defined by its integral and its derivative?

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, physics, mathematical-physics

I was trying to solve a physics problem. The question is: "How long will it take for a boat to cross a river if its velocity is always directed towards a fixed point on the opposite side of the river bank, assuming the velocity of the boat is greater than the water's velocity?".
I came to the conclusion that it would be easier to describe the boat's movement if we took the point towards which the boat is directed as moving at a constant velocity equal to the current's velocity.
Thinking about the problem this way, the function describing the boat's $y$ position would satisfy:
$$f'\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{1}{d-x}\right)\ast\left(\frac{v_{river}}{v_{boat}}\ast\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(x\right)\ dx}-f(x)\right)$$
Where $d$ is the width of the river.
We also know that $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0)=0$, and $F(0)=0$.
Is there any way to deduce $f(x)$ knowing this information? Or is there a simpler way to think of the problem in the first place?

Comment: First of all concerning your integral, $\int_0^x f(x)dx$, when it is not the same $x$ within the integral and within the borders of integration you can easily solve it to get $F(x)-F(0)$. Afterwards I would suggest to differentiate with respect to $x$ to get a - maybe even solvable - second order differntial equation.

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned within the comments your notation is a little bit confusing. By assuming the two occuring $x$ within the integral are not the same - at by setting $k=v_{river}/v_{boat}$ we will get

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\left(\frac{1}{d-x}\right)\left(k\int_{0}^{x}f(t) dt-f(x)\right)\\
f'(x)&=\left(\frac{1}{d-x}\right)\left(k[F(x)-F(0)]-f(x)\right)\\
f'(x)&=\left(\frac{1}{d-x}\right)(kF(x)-f(x))\\
(d-x)f'(x)&=kF(x)-f(x)
\end{align}$$

Now differentiate the whole equation w.r.t. $x$ yields to

$$\begin{align}
(d-x)f''(x)-f'(x)&=f(x)-f'(x)\\
f''(x)&=\frac k{d-x} f(x)
\end{align}$$

The solution of this differential equation is - according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%27%3Dk%2F(d-x)y) - is given in terms of the modified Bessel Functions

$$f(x)=c_1\sqrt{k(d-x)}I_1\left(2\sqrt{k(d-x)}\right)+c_2\sqrt{k(d-x)}K_1\left(2\sqrt{k(d-x)}\right)$$

where $I_n(x)$ denotes the modified Bessel Function of the first kind and $K_n(x)$ the modified Bessel Function of the second kind respectively.